# Any place where i can find free flash tutorials

Tags: flash

As the question above, does anyone know where i can get free flash tutorials and plug-ins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [flashkit](http://flashkit.com/) since early 2000. It has an amazing collection of tutorials and source code. Also they have very knowledgeable contributors on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

[Kongregate Labs](http://www.kongregate.com/labs) has a pretty game-centered tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.flashbookmarks.com has a comprehensive list of flash sites, blogs, tutorials, articles, etc that can be viewed on their webpage (without navigating away).